# Sum of function evaluated at roots of polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials

Assume $p$ is a degree $n$ polynomial over $\mathbb C$ with roots $x_1,\dots, x_n$. Is there a way to express
$$\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j)$$
for some given function $f$ as a function of the coefficients of $p$?

In case this is not possible in general:

- Can this be done for say $n=3$?
- Does this work if $f$ itself is a polynomial of small degree?

Example: If $f=\text{id}$, then the sum over the roots is equal to a quotient of coefficients of $p$, by Vieta's formula.

Comment: It is always possible if $f$ is a polynomial, by the [fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials). Not necessarily possible for non-polynomial functions.